# How to make the hash pyramid to be on the right

Tags: c, cs50

in the cs50 project, we have to make a Mario hash pyramid  then right align it to the left and I'm having a pretty hard time doing it and I hope someone could give me some advice

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int c = 0;
    do {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    } while (h > 8 || h < 1); 
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < h; w++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; j < w; j++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

[image: output]

what is needed:

[image]

Comment: Show how the pyramid should look.

Comment: Your output (and the desired output) is pure text, please show it as text directly here, instead of a link to a picture of text.

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation to your code.

Comment: "make the hash pyramid to be on the left?" To me it seems that your output does show a pyramid to the left...

Comment: In addition to showing the desired output, try describing the desired output. Being able to describe what you want is the first step of abstraction and will allow you to come up with an algorithm.

Comment: To anybody who considers answering this, please keep this in mind in order to really help OP on the long run: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: `First hint according to the compromise I linked: If you do not like a "#" at the beginning of a line, what could you do to make it appear more to the          right?`

Comment: Your bracket style is not very consistent. Please use the same style for all the code in one project or question.

Answer (score 2):

try to make two-loop one for the **empty space** you can also use **-**  and second for **#**..

after the align become to left del the **-**

Comment: Biker1422, I welcome what I perceive as an answer according to the link I provided. I.e. no code (yet) and instead some abstract explanation. Good work.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Your comment I perceive as the opposite. It provides (admittedly quite impressively efficient) code without explanation. If OP decides to use that they might fail to understand it and you are denying them the more useful learning experience of being slowly guided.

Comment: No need for a second loop, you can use `printf()` with the length modifier  `*`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I had the test before two days and I succeed. So I know what he means

Comment: @Bilker1422 The `printf()` function can add space characters as padding, with the field with modifier in a conversion  specification of an argument. The field with can be hardcoded in the format string or given as a `int`. See "DESCRIPTION->Format of the format string" and "DESCRIPTION->Field width" of the `printf(3)` man page

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 but in this case he must use a loop

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 to make everything automatic

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 to make it easy for him I said to him to put  `-` to see the pattern and try to find a way

Comment: @Bilker1422 The ones he already has, but he does not need to use an additional loop to print spaces. He can use `printf()` for the spaces on the left. The `*` modifier reads an `int` from the arguments and it can be used as field width. Placing a `*` between `%` and `s` and placing a 42 as an argument before the string makes `printf()` to add spaces till the string uses at least 42 bytes. However, an additional loop is maybe easier to understand.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 ill try ur way if it makes the code shorter

Answer (score 0):

Before checking the code that I'll provide, I strongly advise you to do hard coding for every single line of pyramide. This is the only way you will see and understand the design pattern of the following algorithm. Then, feel free to check the following code snippet.

Here is the code that builds pyramid right-aligned.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = 0;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Please enter a height between 1 and 8 (inclusive)\nHeight: ");
    }
    while (height > 8 || height < 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = height - i; j > 1; j--)
        {
            printf(" "); // print empty spaces.
        }
        for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
        {
           printf("#"); // print hashes.
        }
        printf("\n"); // go to next line.
    }
}
```